# Sort a matrix based on the order given in a second matrix (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, sorting

I have a bigmatrix that is sorted.  However, I need to re-order it as per the order of IDs in another matrix (`col. 1 here for both matrices`).  How can I do this using vectorization?  Eg:

```
bigmat = [ ...
            1 10 ; 
            1 30 ; 
            1 40 ; 
            2 1  ; 
            2 11 ; 
            3 58 ; 
            4 2  ;
            4 5 ] ;

ordermat = [ 2 ; 1 ; 4 ; 3 ; 6] ;       % Integer IDs

finalans = [ ...
            2 1  ; 
            2 11 ; 
            1 10 ; 
            1 30 ; 
            1 40 ;
            4 2  ;
            4 5  ;
            3 58 ; ] ;
```

It is possible that all some IDs (integers here) in `ordermat` may not be present in bigmat.  They can be ignored as shown above with `id = 6`.  Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by vectorization?

Comment: I meant without using a for-loop on bigmatrix.  I hope the solution uses a function like `ismember` etc.  Bigmatrix has over 0.5 million rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
%# Input values:
bigmat = [1 10; 1 30; 1 40; 2 1; 2 11; 3 58;  4 2; 4 5];
ordermat = [ 2 ; 1 ; 4 ; 3 ; 6] ;   

%# Make a look-up table that tells us the relative order for each order id
sortmat(ordermat) = 1:length(ordermat);

%# Extract the order ID's from the big matrix
keys = bigmat(:,1);

%# Get the new ordering
new_key = sortmat(keys);

%# Sort the new ordering, remembering the permutation necessary
[~, permutation] = sort(new_key);

%# Apply the permutation to the big matrix
finalans = bigmat(permutation, :);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution:

```
ordermat = [2; 1; 4; 3; 6];
bigmat = [
    1 10
    1 30
    1 40
    2 1
    2 11
    3 58
    4 2
    4 5
];
%#bigmat = sortrows(bigmat,1);

%# keep valid IDs, 
ord = ordermat( ismember(ordermat,bigmat(:,1)) );
ord = grp2idx(ord);

%# starting/ending locations of the different IDs in bigmat
startInd = find( diff([0;bigmat(:,1)]) );
endInd = [startInd(2:end)-1; size(bigmat,1)];

%# generate startInd(i):endInd(i) intervals
ind = arrayfun(@colon, startInd, endInd, 'UniformOutput',false);

%# order then combine the intervals of indices
ind = [ind{ord}];

%# get final sorted result
finalans = bigmat(ind,:);
```

I made sure it handles different cases like:

- `ordermat` contains IDs not found in `bigmat`: `ordermat = [2;1;4;3;6]`
- not all IDs of `bigmat` are represented in `ordermat`: `ordermat = [2;1]`
- IDs not sequential and/or not starting at 1: `ordermat=ordermat+10; bigmat=bigmat+10;`

Comment: Does `grp2idx` require the statistics toolbox?

Comment: @nibot: yes it does, but its a very popular toolbox that I assume everyone has it :)

Comment: we can use the third argument of the UNIQUE function instead of GRP2IDX

Answer (score 0):

I'd split `bigmat` into chunks according to the unique identifiers, and then reorder the chunks, like this:

```
%# this assumes bigmat is sorted, btw
%# i.e. that the different ids are grouped together

%# find unique ids
dd = [true;diff(bigmat(:,1))~=0];

uniqueIDs = bigmat(dd,1);

%# reorder uniqueIDs
[~,newOrder] = ismember(uniqueIDs,ordermat);

%# if there are uniqueIDs that are not in ordermat
%# we'd need to remove those. I assume this won't
%# be the case

%# chop up bigmat
numUniqueIds = diff([find(dd);length(dd)+1]);
bigChunks = mat2cell(bigmat,numUniqueIds,size(bigmat,2));

%# reorder chunks
finalans = cat(1,bigChunks{newOrder});
```

Comment: an alternative is to number ordermat, use intlut to replace each index value with it's number, then use sortrows, followed by the reverse intlut.  hope that's clear - i don't know enough matlab to post a full answer, so adding as a comment.